# Bitcoint Core Gui will not display once index is loaded

Tags: bitcoin-core, client

I have the most recent Bitcoin Core "QT" for 64 bit Windows running on my system, It is working from what I can tell via the debug log. The splash screen loads and displays the loading and rewinding of the index. And when, I gather, it reaches 100%, the window minimizes and will  not restore. It remains on the taskbar as a program running. The little app by the clock is there and a right click brings up a menu. But I cannot see the actual account details. [image]

I am able to quit the program safely. I did so and reinstalled a fresh version but there is no change. The program worked properly, previously. Because of some hardware power problem recently in my region I have not always run the code.

Like I say, the code is working but the Gui screen simply does not display. I gather I can run bitcoind instead and use a CLI, but does anyone know of a way to get the GUI back?

Comment: Which version of Bitcoin Core are you using?

Comment: Bitcoin Core 0.13.1

Comment: I am having same problem I used to have core 0.13.1 I uplgraded to 0.14.0-win64 and GUI is not showing eventhoug the core seems to be running

Answer (score 2):

If you go into the task manager (ctrl + shift + esc),  expand Bitcoin Core and left click and click maximize it will show up.